# I'm combining fields in an access query and I need the last number to show a certain number of digits

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Current code is:

```
[Plant] & "" & [CurrentYear] & "" & [CurrentMonth] & "" & [ID]
```

This gives me LO14A2, where `[Plant]=LO`, `[CurrentYear]=14`, `[CurrentMonth]=A`, `[ID]=2` but `[ID]` is supposed to be 00002. What should I have the format as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Right("00000" & [ID],5)
```

So:

```
[Plant] & [CurrentYear] & [CurrentMonth] & Right("00000" & [ID],5)
```